# Is there a way to get fixed size for child inside GridView?

Tags: flutter, dart, user-interface, gridview

Is there a way to have a fixed size for the child inside `GridView`? I wanted to have the red color be same height. I tried using `Expanded` or specified the size for the `Container`, but it just won't work. `GridView` just makes the child same size.

Note: I tried specify the height for the red Container. It didn't work.

This is what I got.

[image]

This is what I did.

```
    return GridView.count(
      crossAxisCount: 2,
      children: List.generate(drinksData.length, (index) {
        return Container(
          padding: EdgeInsets.all(20.0),
          child: Column(
            children: [
              Expanded(
                child: Container(
                  color: Colors.red,
                ),
              ),
              Text(drinksData[index].label),
            ],
          ),
        );
      }),
    );
```

Comment: Yes! Just add `height: 100` in the container

Comment: Hey Davis, thanks for the reply but I tried with specifying the height. It did not work. GridView just makes it equal for the child. You can try it out with the code.

Comment: Check the updated code!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

````
GridView.count(
     crossAxisCount: 2,
     children: List.generate(drinksData.length, (index) {
       return Container(
         padding: const EdgeInsets.all(20.0),
         child: Column(
           children: [
             Expanded(
               child: Container(
                // height:90,//or whatever size you want!
                 color: Colors.red,
               ),
             ),
             SizedBox(
               height: 45,
                 child: Text(drinksData[index])
             ),
           ],
         ),
       );
     }),
   )
   ```
````

Comment: First! to make it seamless! Know the maximum height of your text then provide that in the sizedbox and also handle overflow behavior in the case the text overthrows the height!

Comment: Ahh. that helps, thanks alot Davis! Have a great day!

Comment: Most welcomed!!!